# Login dropdown displayed on hovering itself css3

Tags: html, css, animation

It has a link named "Login/Register" and has an image in the bottom initially. On hovering the link, a box gets drop down (Forget the style used in box).

Coming to the question. The image is of no use to me. I deleted the `img` tag and reloaded the page. Now, when I hover below the Login link (not over it) the box appears.  I wanted the box to appear only when hovering on link, note that it works fine when the image is there.

```css
.nav div.submenu, .nav ul.children, #header .yit_cart_widget .widget_shopping_cart_content, #header .sbHolder .sbOptions, #topbar .widget_nav_menu ul.menu ul.sub-menu, #lang_sel li > ul, #wcml_currency_switcher ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1.732px 3px 0px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.19 );
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1.732px 3px 0px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.19 );
  box-shadow: 1px 1.732px 3px 0px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.19 );
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -26px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

#welcome-menu-login .login-box form.login {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}

.nav li:hover > div.submenu,
.nav li:hover > ul.children,
#header .yit_cart_widget:hover .widget_shopping_cart_content,
#header .yit_cart_widget .widget_shopping_cart_content.active,
#header .sbHolder .sbOptions,
#header .shop-by-category:hover > div.submenu,
#topbar .widget_nav_menu ul.menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu,
#lang_sel li:hover > ul,
#wcml_currency_switcher ul li ul {
    z-index: 10000;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
                                 <div id="welcome-menu-login" class="nav">
                                    <ul id="menu-welcome-login">
                                       <li class="menu-item login-menu dropdown">
                                          <a href="http://live.yithemes.com/nielsen/my-account/">Login/Register</a>
                                          <div class="submenu clearfix">
                                             <div class="clearfix login-box with_registration">
                                                <div id="customer_login">
                                                   <div class="customer-login-box customer-login-box1">
                                                      <form method="post" class="login">
                                                         <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="username">Username or email address <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username">
                                                         </div>
                                                         <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="password">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
                                                         </div>
                                                         <div class="form-group login-submit">
                                                            <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="50d289eef4"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/nielsen/">                                                    <input type="submit" class="button btn btn-flat-red button-login" name="login" value="Login">
                                                            <p class="lost_password">
                                                               <a href="http://live.yithemes.com/nielsen/my-account/lost-password/">Lost password?</a><br>
                                                               New Customer ? <a class="signup" href="http://live.yithemes.com/nielsen/my-account/">Sign up</a>
                                                            </p>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </form>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>

                        <img src="http://www.cigarsnapshot.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/ad-placeholder250x250.gif">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jm8q32t7/.

Comment: Instead of trying to sidestep the SO rule of posting your code in your question when linking to jsFiddle, why don't you do what's asked of you?

Comment: html and css used is simple bit lengthy that makes irritating to those who read. Thats why opted this.

Comment: Narrow your code down to just what is relevant.

Comment: Apologize for the mistakes. I have narrowed the code.

Comment: you mind using JS/jquery?

Comment: Anything is welcome. :) @Siddharth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements with `opacity: 0;` still react to mouse events (clicks, hovers) thus the content will appear when hovering any area it covers.

The reason it worked with the image, is related to z-index. The submenu has `z-index:-1` and the image has a positive value (hence no explicit declaration).

In case of user mouse events, first priority is the element with the highest z-index - the image. Once the image is removed, the submenu becomes first priority.

You can use `visibility` property to make elements transparent to mouse events. Use the following combo:

```
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
```

and

```
visibility:visible;
opacity:1;
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48cgc5jc/2/).

Comment: Perfect simple solution. Thanks for the effort and explanation on this.

Answer (score 1):

i tried applying `Jquery`,thing is your menu(`div.submenu`) is sibling of link(`a.link`) so it is not possible (i tried a lot and i would appreciate it someone comes up with it) to do it with CSS,so here is another solution in Jquery. have a look.

i applied `CSS` rules to `div.submenu` element when you `mouseover` on link and toggled it.

```
 $('.menu-item ').hover(function(){
    console.log(1111);
     $('div.submenu').show();
  },function(){
   $('div.submenu').hide();
  });
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5oeq68kj/) doing same

Comment: Thanks for your effort buddy. But lost the animation from your code.